# Bounds on the probability of no edges on a certain graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

I'm facing this graph problem where I need to bound the probability of having no edges in a certain graph:

Suppose we have a graph G with n nodes and m edges, which all its nodes' degrees are bounded by a constant d. We will build a new graph G' by choosing only some of the nodes from G: each node will be picked with probability of $p = {1}/{log(m)}$ (independently).

I need to prove these two bounds of **Pr[G' has no edges]**:

- Pr[G' has no edges] $< {(1-p^2)}^{(1+o(1))m}$
- Pr[G' has no edges] $> {(1-p^2)}^{(1-o(1))m}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think the proof must use either the local lemma or the Poisson paradigm. Either way, o(1) might be a function that depends on m and is infinitesimal (as m gets larger), and can depend on d too (since its a constant). also o(1) functions in each bound proofs can be different.